# Знаки препинания при обращении - слитном сочетании

Tags: пунктуация, обращение

В одном из стихотворений современного автора прочитала:

> Эх элита, ты элита -
>
> Из каких людей ты свита?

https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5e14665a98930900b3abdb84/kto-elita-nasha-boje-5eda59f41916e14afcebf150

Что-то не понравилась пунктуация. Во-первых, после междометия ЭХ должна быть запятая, это понятно, а вот "элита ты элита" не относится к неразложимым сочетаниям? Я бы здесь паузы не сделала, а значит, и запятой бы не поставила. Материала по теме не нашла. Как вы думаете, нужна запятая или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примеров не нашёл. Но написал бы так: *Эх, элита ты элита, Из каких людей ты свита?*

Если поставить запятую перед или после "ты", то сочетания "ты элита" или "элита ты" приобретут вид двусоставных предложений с  утверждением "элитности" этого "ты"…

Нужно же только обращение. Ставить же запятые после каждого слова: *Эх, элита, ты, элита, Из каких…* — это уже будет перебор...

Comment: Да вот я тоже так думаю, ну, тире - это ещё как-то может быть оправдано: подчёркивается смысл иронии в двух частях, а остальное никак не оправдаешь.